# RAID vs DFS: What's the difference?

Tags: performance, raid, dfs

I know the question sounds quite stupid, as to why RAID (Redundant Array of Inexpensive Disks) is compared with DFS (Distributed File System), I may get downvoted.

First of all, I'm aware that RAID is used on a single system to provide better fault tolerance and redundancy and has been in wide use for relatively longer time. On the other hand, DFS, like Hadoop DFS (please don't take me wrong, I am still relatively new to the world of Hadoop and Big Data), provides redundancy by storing data on multiple clusters which are again considered commodity hardware.

What I am curious about is how the two differ in the aspect of their performance, usage (apart from their implementation) and whether they can be used interchangeably (stupid question). If a DFS was implemented using RAID like system, will it benefit or suffer (sure suffer is the answer but how much)?

Comment: RAID is a single system storage configuration, DFS is a way of spreading data across multiple systems for redundancy and access purposes. They are two entirely different things. They exist apart from each other and one does not impact the other in any substantial ways. Don't confuse storage with data.

Comment: I think this is off-topic here as its opinion based, and I'm pretty sure you know the answers based on your statements, as are a natural consequence.  The question about DFS implemented using a RAID like system is open to interpretation - you could put a DFS system on RAID or use a DFS system to produce RAID like characteristics

Comment: @davidgo yes that's my doubt. I just wanna know if this kind of idea has been previously implemented and if yes then where. And if this question is off-topic for Superuser (a fellow on SOF asked me to switch to Superuser for this question), where does it belong to?

Comment: I don't see it as an opinion question as it can be answered with facts. It might be classed as too broad but I see you've already got at least one answer

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is RAID is a block level technology and DFS is a file level technology. Apart from the obvious other differences.

File level technology is problematic when files are in use or locked. It is also inefficient as it often requires retransmitting the entire file even when only a single byte changes. It is not uncommon for replication problems to occur with DFS for this reason. Because it relies on the NTFS journal, if the system is shutdown improperly, or too many changes occur since the last replication DFS is forced to rescan every single file on the volume which can take days.

DFS is ancient technology designed for slow, inefficient WAN connections. The replacement technology is a storage replica stretch cluster. This works at the block level and is immune to file locking, and syncs only changed blocks.

With that said, both of these technologies (DFS and storage replicas) typically run on top of a RAID subsystem.